# Adaptive Thresholding Technique to live videos from webcam C#

Tags: c#, detection, aforge, light

I am trying to detect light from 2 LED lights (red and blue) I did that using Bernsen thresholding technique. However, I applied that to an image. Now I want to apply that same technique but to a live video from my webcam. Is there anyway I could simply edit the code for this technique on the image to make it work on a video from the webcam? I will add below the code I used for this thresholding technique.

```
private ArrayList getNeighbours(int xPos, int yPos, Bitmap bitmap)
        {
           //This goes around the image in windows of 5 

            ArrayList neighboursList = new ArrayList();

            int xStart, yStart, xFinish, yFinish;

            int pixel;

            xStart = xPos - 5;
            yStart = yPos - 5;


            xFinish = xPos + 5;
            yFinish = yPos + 5;


            for (int y = yStart; y <= yFinish; y++)
            {
                for (int x = xStart; x <= xFinish; x++)
                {

                    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > (bitmap.Width - 1) || y > (bitmap.Height - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y).R;

                        neighboursList.Add(pixel);
                    }
                }
            }

            return neighboursList;
        }


private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //The input image
            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = image.Height - 1;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);

            int iMin, iMax, t, c, contrastThreshold, pixel;

            contrastThreshold = 180;

            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    list.Clear();

                    pixel = image.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                    list = getNeighbours(x, y, image);
                    list.Sort();


                    iMin = Convert.ToByte(list[0]);

                    iMax = Convert.ToByte(list[list.Count - 1]);

                    // These are the calculations to test whether the 
                       current pixel is light or dark

                    t = ((iMax + iMin) / 2);


                    c = (iMax - iMin);


                    if (c < contrastThreshold)
                    {

                        pixel = ((t >= 160) ? 0 : 255);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixel = ((pixel >= t) ? 0 : 255);
                    }

                    result.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixel, pixel, pixel));                    
                }

                progressBar1.Value = y;


            }

            pictureBox3.Image =result;
        }
```

Comment: The video feed is a stream of image data so why not? You'd have to capture frames to analyse. Depending on performance I'd probably only process several frames per second rather than every frame. What have you tried?

Comment: I could try that. Capturing frames and analyzing them. But question is would this process give me live results? Because I need to detect the light in real time.

Comment: That question is easily answered by another question: how quickly does this procedure detect light in a still frame. If it's within a second or so you can detect light every second that you feed it a frame, if it takes 30 seconds to run then no, you will have a 30 second lead time. Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: Hi again. So I have tried it and I finally applied the thresholding technique to the live stream however it turned out to be SUPER slow. I am currently looking for more lightweight techniques for real time processing. Thanks